# Add glitter text

Tags: php, gd

I want to add effect on the text in PHP and append it on image. 
current code, which use GD library to put text into the image.

```
   $name = str_replace('-', ' ', $_POST["text"]); 
   putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));

   $font_path = './css/font.ttf';
   $font_path = realpath($font_path);

   $directory = "images_bg/";
   $images = preg_grep('~\.(jpeg|jpg|png)$~', scandir($directory));
   $i = rand(0, count($images) - 1);
   $upload_dir = 'gen_images/';
   $t=time();
   $image_mime = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($directory.$images[$i]));
   if($image_mime == 'application/octet-stream'){
     return 0;
   }
   if($image_mime == 'image/jpeg'){
    $new_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($directory.$images[$i]);

    imagettftext($new_image, 40, 0, 105, 60, $white, $font_path, $name);

    ob_start();
    @imagegif($new_image,$upload_dir.'image_'.$t.'.jpg');
    printf('<img id="gen_img" src="'.$upload_dir.'image_'.$t.'.jpg"/>');
    imagedestroy($new_image);
```

So the question is how I can add glittering text over that text.

I have some glittering gif as an example which I dont know how to apply in text.

[image: Example GIF]

Greetings. (If i did not provided enought info, tell in comment).

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. Do you want to have a glittering effect (more like a noise effect) in a static image? I'm not sure it will look like glittering if it is not a GIF.

Comment: I want to add glittering effect on text, which I put into an image (imagettftext). [Like this()](https://diosesbueno.com/frase-secreta/gen_images/image_1448548180.jpg). Text "Ales" is the one which i added on image.

Answer (score 0):

This code pen may help: http://codepen.io/Azayles/pen/avBZYN

```
 <div class="Sparkle">
    YOUR TEXT HERE
</div>

.Sparkle {

    font-size:100px;
    font-family:impact;

 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
             url(http://www.myspacehippo.com/files/glitterbacks/bg345.gif) repeat;
 background: -o-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

I personally don't know how to transfer it over to php, but someone might and can comment on this answer. For the background, the person used this website: http://www.myspacehippo.com/

The background is a gif on repeat, so maybe you can try that